# Change the number to the text assigned to it

Tags: excel

I have sth like this:

[image]

It has 80k rows.

[image]

It has 2k rows.

I want to convert the numbers from column C to the text that I will get from column G (featuresval_id2=featuresval_id )

Comment: you need [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). It does exactly what you want

Comment: VLOOKUP() or INDEX() with MATCH(). Lots of examples on here.

Comment: I used ablebits data and vlookup wizard to achive what i wanted to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a bran new column with this formula (for example to write into H2..):
=index(G:G; match(C2;F:F;0))

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize match() and index() function in Excel.

`match()` will return the position of an item in an array. The item here is `C2` in `featuresval_id` array. The array we want to search into is `featuresval_id2`. The `0` is saying that we want exact match.

```
MATCH(C2,featuresval_id2, 0)
```

After finding the relative position, we can use `index()` to get the value in another array - which you call `name`

```
=INDEX(name,MATCH(C2,featuresval_id2, 0))
```

Hope that helps.